# adding a variable to string in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using react native to create a podcast. I have stored the details for each podcast and I have using php to store the data in json format so that I can use them with in react native. I have been using react-native-sound in order to play the sound within my app.

I want to add the the variable to the file path for the sound.

I want the code to be

```js
this.sound = new Sound('sound.mp3', Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, (error) =>
```

I have tried the following but it doesn't work.

```js
this.sound = new Sound(this.state.FileUrlHolder, Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, (error) =>
```

```js
this.sound = new Sound("'" + this.state.FileUrlHolder + "'", Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, (error) =>
```

```js
this.sound = new Sound(`${this.state.FileUrlHolder}`, Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, (error) =>
```

```js
this.sound = new Sound(`{this.state.FileUrlHolder}`, Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, (error) =>
```

Comment: What's in `this.state.FileUrlHolder`?

Comment: The first one this.sound = new Sound(this.state.FileUrlHolder, Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, (error) => should work, how do you set this.state.FileUrlHolder?

Comment: Assuming that the JSON contains *urls*, I don't think you can play those. `new Sound()` expects a filename pointing to a file bundled into the app as part of the `res/raw` folder.

Comment: the JSON does contain urls

Comment: this.setState({
        FileUrlHolder : responseJson[0].FileUrl 
      })

Comment: I looked at the docs and it supports playing remote files; what is the error you're getting? Are you following [this](https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound-demo/blob/master/main.js) with your implementation? Also, looking at this, have you tried passing `null` instead of `Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE` as 2nd argument? Given that a remote sound is definitely *not* in the main bundle.

Comment: tried adding null but still the file doesn't play

Comment: So what is the error you're getting?

Comment: no error, the file just doesn't play

Comment: The 3rd argument needs to be something like `(error, sound) => { if (!error) sound.play(); }` what do you have there?

Comment: that didn't seem to fix the problem